# Access JWT token from first curl request and pass it to next curl post

Tags: curl, .net-core, jwt

I have a .netcore 2.1 API. I am trying to implement JWT in it for security.

I am planning to invoke the api from a cUrl script.

My problem is how can I make the first curl script to get the token and then pass this token to the next curl script.

I want to write just one curl script to access jwt token and use it in next post as this will be run from the login step of a Mac.

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**
The curl scripts I have,

```
curl -X PUT "https://localhost:5000/api/token" -H "accept: application/json" -d "Content-Length: 0"


curl -X PUT "http://localhost:5000/api/values" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXIAMBEARER" -d "Content-Length: 0"
```

So is someting like below possible

```
TOKEN=curl -X PUT "https://localhost:5000/api/token" -H "accept: application/json" -d "Content-Length: 0"

curl -X PUT "http://localhost:5000/api/values" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer {TOKEN}" -d "Content-Length: 0"
```

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f %%A in ('curl -X "POST" "http://localhost:5000/api/jwt/login" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "Username=admin" -F "Password=mypass"') do set token=%%A
    
echo %token%

echo off

(set result=)


for /F %%I in ('curl -X "GET" "http://localhost:5000/api/arsys/v1.0/entry/ASTComputerSystem" -H "accept: */*" -H "Authorization: AR-JWT %token%"') do (
CALL set result=%%result%%%%I
)


echo on
echo %result%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Hello world!");
var objShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");

var exe = objShell.Exec('curl -X \"POST\" \"http://localhost:5000/api/jwt/login\" -H \"accept: */*\" -H \"Content-Type: multipart/form-data\" -F \"Username=admin\" -F \"Password=mypass\"');

var token = exe.StdOut.ReadAll();

WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(token);

exe = objShell.Exec('curl -X \"GET\" \"http://localhost:5000/api/arsys/v1.0/entry/ASTComputerSystem\" -H \"accept: */*\" -H \"Authorization: AR-JWT '+ token);

var result = exe.StdOut.ReadAll();

WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(result);
```